# Get deeplinks of Wikimedia Commons pictures

Tags: json, bash, parsing, mediawiki-api, wikimedia-commons

I would like to get the fulltext URL from Wikimedia Commons pictures. As example I would like to get https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/69/Trittin%2C_J%C3%BCrgen-0126.jpg from [File:Trittin, Jürgen-0126.jpg](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Trittin,_J%C3%BCrgen-0126.jpg). Here is the html source:

```
<div class="fullMedia"><a href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/69/Trittin%2C_J%C3%BCrgen-0126.jpg" class="internal" title="Trittin, Jürgen-0126.jpg">Original file</a> &#8206;<span class="fileInfo">(1,996 × 3,000 pixels, file size: 2.2 MB, MIME type: <span class="mime-type">image/jpeg</span>)</span>
</div>
```

Because I'm doing many queries I would prefer a lightweight unix tools solution over such a thing like BeautifulSoup. There is also an API ([commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=imageinfo&titles=File:Trittin,_J%C3%BCrgen-0126.jpg&iiprop=url](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=imageinfo&titles=File:Trittin,_J%C3%BCrgen-0126.jpg&iiprop=url)), but for me as a simple bash scripter JSON is an imposition!

I'm glad if you could help me.

Comment: [tag:jq] eases the JSON woes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace in URL

```
File:
```

with

```
Special:FilePath/
```

Answer (score 0):

My hack using curl and grep:

```
 curl -s https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Trittin,_J%C3%BCrgen-0126.jpg | grep fullImageLink | grep -o  'http[^ ]*jpg'
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you should use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).

```
curl --silent 'https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&formatversion=2&action=query&prop=imageinfo&titles=File:Trittin,_J%C3%BCrgen-0126.jpg&iiprop=url' | jq --raw-output '.query.pages[0].imageinfo[0].url'
```